# Is there any ready to use module for test feedback for web applications?

Tags: c#, asp.net, testing, web-applications

I want to implement test feedback in my web application in the following manner - when a user with testing privileges logs in, every page in the web app will open small feedback window and dock it to the corner. Testers can use this window to describe the issue, and eventually add attachments. On confirmation, the module saves that data in the database and records relevant data like browser version, serialize relevant objects etc...

Is there anything like that already implemented as free for use module ?

Thx.

**EDIT**:
Talking about ASP.NET, I envision this as a class that inherits Page, implementing defaults. To enable testing you inherit from this class. After the testing is complete you could disable the entire thing by inheriting from Page again...

The database configuration could be set up using web.config. The class could also provide overridable methods like *WriteIssue(Context c, UserInput input)* which default implementation uses web.config and some hardcoded table you need to provide in you database. Then, if you need other type of storage, like for example creating issue on issue server, you could override this method to provide custom implementation. Web.config could also contain other customizations like dock type, window css and similar...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I developed little Feedback library to solve above goals. 
The documentation, source and compilled assembly are available [here](http://code.google.com/p/feedbackpage/).

Answer (score 1):

> Talking about ASP.NET, I envision this
>   as a class that inherits Page,
>   implementing defaults. To enable
>   testing you inherit from this class.
>   After the testing is complete you
>   could disable the entire thing by
>   inheriting from Page again...

Although it's an interesting idea, I see a few problems with this approach:

1. It would mean a **different code base for testing and for production**. You will then never be sure the production version behaves exactly like the test version.
2. How would you handle **situations that are outside of a single Page's scope**? One example: what happens if the tester encounters an application failure (unavailable DB connection, error in configuration etc)?

There are other ways to achieve similar goals: one would be to automatically record the whole test session (screenshots, user's actions) and store that in a HTML report. Some automatic Web testing tools [can do it](http://binil.wordpress.com/2006/12/22/taking-screenshots-with-selenium/), I don't know about manual testing tools (but it's probably available).

Comment: 1. You are right. I now think more about using conditional for that. So the production and testing code can differ only in symbol declaration. Also, the code could be kept intact on production as without testing priv. it should do nothing. 2. I am not aiming to handle fatal errors this way. About your proposal, I don't like the idea as its not my goal plus the technique seems to need Java installed. Automatic screenshoting is something I am currently looking for, but in JS environment. It turns out its easy to do in IE, but not so easy in other browsers